# Android Studio 3.4 Canary 3 Compile error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I cannot perform clean build, rebuild with the latest preview version of Android Studio, doing so will thrown an error.

```
Unsupported type 
(com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$Version) found for field 
'rangeStart' while constructing immutable class 
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$VersionRange.
Immutable classes only support properties with effectively immutable types including:
- Strings, primitive types, wrapper types, Class, BigInteger and BigDecimal, enums
- classes annotated with @KnownImmutable and known immutables (java.awt.Color, java.net.URI)
- Cloneable classes, collections, maps and arrays, and other classes with special handling
  (java.util.Date and various java.time.* classes and interfaces)
Other restrictions apply, please see the groovydoc for ImmutableOptions for further details
```

Performing `gradlew clean` resulting to this

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
```

What are the meaning and solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix the problem by updating to the latest google services right [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/4.2.0)
then update my firebase dependencies to the latest.

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, you should downgrade the google-services version to **3.2.0** in project level build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
```

Will update here once I have more info about this.